# How do I highlight available days in a Calendar control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, calendar

I wanted to highlight some range of days in a Calendar in WPF, and make any other day in the calendar unavailable. So the user could select only the highlighted range. The problem is, I havent found anything useful to do so yet. The control itself doesnt support data binding at all (although it has Data Context property :-)), which makes it somewhat sloppy.

Answer (score 2):

To make some dates unavailable you can use `Calendar.BlackoutDates` property. E.g.:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
_calendar.BlackoutDates.Add(
    new CalendarDateRange(today.AddDays(-5), today.AddDays(-3)));
```